# Most ideal way to update a RavenDB collection, without an index

Tags: c#, ravendb

I want to update a collection of documents, which are dynamically queries e.g. without an index. Here is a (pseudo) sample that works:

```cs
void ChangeOwnerShip(string oldName, string newName) {

    var collection = session.Query<GummyBears>()
        .Where(p => p.OwnerName == oldName);

    foreach (var doc in collection) {
        doc.OwnerName == newName;
    }

    session.SaveChanges();
}
```

In the sample above I don't take the limit of documents you can and may ask from RavenDB into account ("safe by default"). But simply put: it works. I haven't created an index for this and RavenDB lists a dynamic index upon usage, which seems to work just fine.

But with all the nifty features in RavenDB, I'm convinced this isn't the most ideal way to do this.

Samples provided for Partial document updates, [Batch operations](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/advanced/databasecommands/batch) seem to be designed for this purpose. However, the samples all seem to relate to a single document only - and I can't seem to find a decent explanation on how to get this working with a collection of objects.

Also, the HTTP API has some decent samples on [multi document operations](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/http-api/http-api-multi). In fact, the section *Set based updates* there provides exactly the type of scenario I want to achieve. It requires the creation of an index first, though.

Still, I can't seem to find a decent example on how to simply update a dynamic collection with the .NET client. In short the question is: what would be **a better, or more advisable approach** on a simple update of a collection, than my sample above?

Answer (score 0):

If you collection is small,it will work just fine.
RavenDB will create an index behind the scenes for you.